# How to create a relational factorisation recommender?

Tags: python, recommender-system

I want to create a recommender system with factorisation recommander.
We have scores on hashtags, ads have scores on hashtags, and we even have scores of subscriber on ads.
We want to use this to recommend ads to subscriber.

- Scores of suscriber on hastags (but not all of them) :

called `df_p`

```
    count  hashtag_id  subscriber_id
0      22         321            172
1      44         321            161
2      25         322            172
3       6         323            172
4      32         325            172
5      26         328            161
...   ...         ...            ...
```

- Scores of ads on hashtags (but not all of them):

called `df_q`

```
      count  eclipse_id  hashtag_id
0         1        6521         321
1         1        6606         321
2         1        6609         321
3         1        6617         321
4         1        6649         321
5         1        6911         321
...      ...        ...         ...
```

- Scores of subscriber on ad (still: not all of them):

How can I use GraphLab `factorization_recommender` to recommand ad to suscriber ?

The output should be (here for a given user 13):

```
subscriber_id   eclipse_id  score   rank
13  6565    0.059975420017  1
13  6588    0.0389804676959     2
13  9762    0.0159731995118     3
13  9606    0.0159731995118     4
13  9854    0.0159731995118     5
13  9576    0.0159731995118     6
13  9902    0.0155536116738     7
13  9875    0.0155536116738     8
13  6766    0.0126994707082     9
13  9870    0.0125380719963     10
```

---

On the GraphLab official website, I already found :

```
user_info = graphlab.SFrame({'user_id': ["0", "1", "2"],
                              'name': ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
                              'numeric_feature': [0.1, 12, 22]})
item_info = graphlab.SFrame({'item_id': ["a", "b", "c", d"],
                              'name': ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
                              'dict_feature': [{'a' : 23}, {'a' : 13},
                                               {'b' : 1},
                                               {'a' : 23, 'b' : 32}]})
m2 = graphlab.factorization_recommender.create(sf, target='rating',
                                                user_data=user_info,
                                                item_data=item_info)
```

But it seems not to apply to my case as far as here we have scores on user and scores on item. My project is more relational as described above.

---

I already tried like wihout the relational features :

```
products = pd.DataFrame(r_cols)
# We fill NaN cells with 0s
products['eclipse_id'] = products['eclipse_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)
# We transform it to an SFrame
sf = SFrame(data=products)
# We split data to train the model
ratings_base,ratings_test = sf.random_split(.8, seed=0)
# We train the model
# Train Model
personalized_model = graphlab.item_similarity_recommender.create(ratings_base, user_id='subscriber_id', item_id='eclipse_id', target='count', similarity_type='cosine')
```

Allowing me to recommend (but I don't know on the basis of what) :

```
personalized_model.recommend(users=[users[0]])
```

Giving me back :

```
subscriber_id   eclipse_id  score   rank
172     11279   5.42914502761        1
172     11275   1.65434508464        2
172     0       0.139058996649       3
172     11268   0.0788922800737      4
```

Comment: It's a GraphLab question, and here I cannot help. However, for recommendation systems you can use pure TensorFlow (see e.g. this example, with the same form of data: https://github.com/warchildmd/game2vec) or this implementation of Factorization Machines (also, in TensorFlow): https://github.com/geffy/tffm/ (which I use).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Thanks a lot, the second one looks like what I am looking for. Can you confirm me that I can provide an array of scores between users on items and an array of scores of users on features and an array of scores of items on features and get a prediction for the yet to be rated items for each users ?

Comment: You mean:  user-item scores, item-features scores, want to predict user-item for yet unseen? Then - yes.


For context, I recommend reading paper linked here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/65d3lt/r_factorization_machines_2010_a_classic_paper_in/

Comment: You might find https://github.com/actionml/universal-recommender useful -- in principle it can do what you're looking for.